# how to check the master volume is muted or not

Tags: vb.net

*how to check the master volume is muted in windows 7 OS* 
  I have the code for mute or unmute 
  i.e

```
Public Const APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE As Integer = &H80000
Public Const APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP As Integer = &HA0000
Public Const APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN As Integer = &H90000
Public Const WM_APPCOMMAND As Integer = &H319
Declare Function SendMessageW Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
MM.SendMessageW(Me.Handle, MM.WM_APPCOMMAND, Me.Handle, CType(MM.APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE, IntPtr))
```

here i wont to check only mute condition of master valume.

than q in advance.

Comment: This might help-- check out [DeviceTopology API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678714.aspx), specifically [IAudioMute Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678773.aspx)

Comment: Actually using an [IAudioEndpointVolume interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370892(v=vs.85).aspx)'s `GetMute` seems a little more straightforward

Answer (score 1):

You can easily check by "core audio.dll" api.

download coreaudio.dll from  [here](https://www.dllme.com/dll/files/coreaudioapi_dll.html)

Refernce it in your project and..

than use the following code:

```
private function getmute() as boolean
    Dim devenum As New MMDeviceEnumerator
    Dim device As MMDevice = devenum.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eMultimedia)
    If device.AudioEndpointVolume.Mute = True Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

hope this works....

(sorry for bad english)