# How to check if the system audio is muted?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winapi, core-audio

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40545562/15498) which recommends using the ["core audio.dll" API](https://www.dllme.com/dll/files/coreaudioapi_dll.html) with the following code:

```vb
private function getmute() as boolean
    Dim devenum As New MMDeviceEnumerator
    Dim device As MMDevice = devenum.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eMultimedia)
    If device.AudioEndpointVolume.Mute = True Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

I tried that code but it doesn't work and I could not leave a comment on the other question.

When I try the above code, the following line throws an exception:

```vb
If device.AudioEndpointVolume.Mute = True Then
```

Here's the exception message:

> AudioEndpointVolume is not a member of device.

I have already imported `CoreAudioAPI`, what else could be wrong?

I'm looking for a `VB.NET` or a `C#` solution.

Comment: are you getting any error message?

Comment: It appears you're referencing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40545562/15498). It's usually best to include such links in your question so that others know what you're talking about.

Comment: Also, do you want the solution in C# or VB.NET? Either, or, or both? You have both languages tagged

Comment: @Fabulous C# or VB.net, easy to convert so thats why I tagged both...

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI ,yes AudioEndpointVolume is not a member of device

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ,yes thats the link, but the solution does not work

Comment: There is no *IAudioEndpointVolume* method for *IMMDevice*. You need `IID_IAudioEndpointVolume` guid to get `IAudioEndpointVolume` object from `IMMDevice`. Then use `GetMute` method. That is actually the way is done using *Windows Core Audio API*.

Comment: @γηράσκω δ' αεί πολλά διδασκόμε , I added the line     Public Shared IID_IAudioEndpointVolume As Guid but still not working, do not understand what to do, have found so mane questions and answers about this, but non works and  no-one answers anyone with something that works..

Comment: An `IAudioEndpointVolume` interface is returned by the IMMDevice interface .Activate()  method. The `IMMDevice` interface is retrieved by the enumerator: `IMMDeviceEnumerator` method `GetDefaultAudioEndpoint()`. After the `IAudioEndpointVolume` instance is returned, you can use its `GetMute()`, `SetMute()` methods to get or set the Mute status of a MM Device.

Comment: @Jimi I still dont understand what to add in my code to make it work, its not just 1-2 rows that are missing? Its hundred of lines like the answer below? I just want a simple solution as possible

Comment: The answer that @γηράσκω δ' αεί πολλά διδασκόμε posted **is** the simple solution. If you don't want to use an existing library (such as [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio)), this is the minimalist code. .Net still doesn't have means to address the [Core Audio APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/CoreAudio/core-audio-apis-in-windows-vista) (just a sparse subset of those functionality). You just need to create a class, stuff the code there and forget about it :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`VB.Net` rewriting (+ Bonus) of the `CoreAudio API` implementation [γηράσκω δ' αεί πολλά διδασκόμε](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52001368/check-if-system-is-muted-vb-net?answertab=active#tab-top) posted.

The code in wrapped in a Class (`AudioDevice`) and includes the original `IsMuted()` method, plus other methods I implemented on the fly (because, why not).

More information on the [Windows CoreAudio APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/CoreAudio/core-audio-apis-in-windows-vista) on MSDN.
GitHub [NAudio CoreAudioApi](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/tree/master/NAudio/CoreAudioApi) implementation (`C#`).

**Methods implemented:**

**`IsMuted() As Integer`**
Return the Muted status of the default Audio Device.

**`SetMute(Boolean)`**
Sets the Muted status of the default Audio Device (`True/False`)

**`IsMediadPlaying()`**
The default Audio Device is currently playing or not

**`GetVolume() As Integer`**
Get the Volume status of the default Audio Device. Values range from `0 to 100`

**`SetVolume(Integer)`**
Set the Volume status of the default Audio Device to a values in the `0 to 100` range

**`VolumeUp()`**
Increases the Volume of the default Audio Device by one step (usually 2 units)

**`VolumeDown()`**
Decreases the Volume of the default Audio Device by one step.

**Usage:**

```vb
 Dim isMuted As Boolean = AudioDevice.IsMuted()

 ' True=Mutes the Audio, False=Un-Mutes (?) it
 AudioDevice.SetMute(True)

 ' Checks whether the Media Device currently playing
 Dim isPlaying As Boolean = AudioDevice.IsMediadPlaying()

 Dim volume As Integer = AudioDevice.GetVolume()

 ' Sets the Audio level to 50%, returns the previous value
 Dim previousVolume As Integer = AudioDevice.SetVolume(50)

 ' Increases the Audio level by 1 Step
 AudioDevice.VolumeUp()

 ' Decreases the Audio level by 1 Step
 AudioDevice.VolumeDown()
```

**Declarations:**

```vb
Imports System
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class AudioDevice
    Friend Enum EDataFlow
        eRender
        eCapture
        eAll
        EDataFlow_enum_count
    End Enum

    Friend Enum ERole
        eConsole
        eMultimedia
        eCommunications
        ERole_enum_count
    End Enum

    <Flags>
    Public Enum CLSCTX As UInteger
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER = &H1
        CLSCTX_INPROC_HANDLER = &H2
        CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER = &H4
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER16 = &H8
        CLSCTX_REMOTE_SERVER = &H10
        CLSCTX_INPROC_HANDLER16 = &H20
        CLSCTX_RESERVED1 = &H40
        CLSCTX_RESERVED2 = &H80
        CLSCTX_RESERVED3 = &H100
        CLSCTX_RESERVED4 = &H200
        CLSCTX_NO_CODE_DOWNLOAD = &H400
        CLSCTX_RESERVED5 = &H800
        CLSCTX_NO_CUSTOM_MARSHAL = &H1000
        CLSCTX_ENABLE_CODE_DOWNLOAD = &H2000
        CLSCTX_NO_FAILURE_LOG = &H4000
        CLSCTX_DISABLE_AAA = &H8000
        CLSCTX_ENABLE_AAA = &H10000
        CLSCTX_FROM_DEFAULT_CONTEXT = &H20000
        CLSCTX_ACTIVATE_32_BIT_SERVER = &H40000
        CLSCTX_ACTIVATE_64_BIT_SERVER = &H80000
        CLSCTX_INPROC = CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER Or CLSCTX_INPROC_HANDLER
        CLSCTX_SERVER = CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER Or CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER Or CLSCTX_REMOTE_SERVER
        CLSCTX_ALL = CLSCTX_SERVER Or CLSCTX_INPROC_HANDLER
    End Enum

    <ComImport, Guid("BCDE0395-E52F-467C-8E3D-C4579291692E")>
    Public Class MMDeviceEnumeratorComObject
    End Class

    <ComImport, Guid("A95664D2-9614-4F35-A746-DE8DB63617E6"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)>
    Friend Interface IMMDeviceEnumerator
        Function NotImpl1() As Integer
        Function GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(
              dataFlow As EDataFlow,
              role As ERole,
              <Out> ByRef ppDevice As IMMDevice) As Integer
    End Interface

    <ComImport, Guid("D666063F-1587-4E43-81F1-B948E807363F"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)>
    Public Interface IMMDevice
        Function Activate(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)> iid As Guid,
                          dwClsCtx As CLSCTX, pActivationParams As IntPtr) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)> Object
    End Interface

    <ComImport, Guid("5CDF2C82-841E-4546-9722-0CF74078229A"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)>
    Public Interface IAudioEndpointVolume
        Function RegisterControlChangeNotify(pNotify As IAudioEndpointVolumeCallback) As Integer
        Function UnregisterControlChangeNotify(pNotify As IAudioEndpointVolumeCallback) As Integer
        Function GetChannelCount(ByRef channelCount As Integer) As Integer
        Function SetMasterVolumeLevel() As Integer
        Function SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(level As Single, eventContext As Guid) As Integer
        Function GetMasterVolumeLevel(<Out> ByRef level As Single) As Integer
        Function GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(<Out> ByRef level As Single) As Integer
        Function SetChannelVolumeLevel(channelNumber As Integer, level As Single, eventContext As Guid) As Integer
        Function SetChannelVolumeLevelScalar(channelNumber As Integer, level As Single, eventContext As Guid) As Integer
        Function GetChannelVolumeLevel(channelNumber As Integer, <Out> ByRef level As Single) As Integer
        Function GetChannelVolumeLevelScalar(channelNumber As Integer, <Out> ByRef level As Single) As Integer
        Function SetMute(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> isMuted As Boolean, eventContext As Guid) As Integer
        Function GetMute(<Out> ByRef isMuted As Boolean) As Integer
        Function GetVolumeStepInfo(<Out> ByRef pnStep As Integer, ByRef pnStepCount As Integer) As Integer
        Function VolumeStepUp(eventContext As Guid) As Integer
        Function VolumeStepDown(eventContext As Guid) As Integer
        Function QueryHardwareSupport(<Out> ByRef hardwareSupportMask As Integer) As Integer
        Function GetVolumeRange(<Out> ByRef volumeMin As Single, <Out> ByRef volumeMax As Single, <Out> ByRef volumeStep As Single) As Integer
    End Interface

    <ComImport, Guid("657804FA-D6AD-4496-8A60-352752AF4F89"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)>
    Public Interface IAudioEndpointVolumeCallback
        <PreserveSig()>
        Function OnNotify(pNotifyData As IntPtr) As Integer  ' HRESULT
    End Interface

    <InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), Guid("C02216F6-8C67-4B5B-9D00-D008E73E0064")>
    Public Interface IAudioMeterInformation
        Function GetPeakValue() As Single
    End Interface

    Public Shared Function IsMuted() As Boolean
        Dim masterVol As IAudioEndpointVolume = GetMasterVolumeObject()
        Try
            If masterVol Is Nothing Then
                Throw New ApplicationException("Master Volume not available")
            End If

            Dim isAudioMuted As Boolean
            masterVol.GetMute(isAudioMuted)
            Return isAudioMuted
        Finally
            If masterVol IsNot Nothing Then
                If masterVol IsNot Nothing Then Marshal.ReleaseComObject(masterVol)
            End If
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Shared Sub SetMute(IsMute As Boolean)
        Dim masterVol As IAudioEndpointVolume = GetMasterVolumeObject()
        Try
            masterVol.SetMute(IsMute, Guid.Empty)
        Finally
            If masterVol IsNot Nothing Then
                If masterVol IsNot Nothing Then Marshal.ReleaseComObject(masterVol)
            End If
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function IsMediadPlaying() As Boolean
        Dim mediaDevice As IMMDevice = Nothing
        Try
            mediaDevice = GetDefaultAudioEndpoint()
            Dim meter = mediaDevice.Activate(GetType(IAudioMeterInformation).GUID, CLSCTX.CLSCTX_ALL, IntPtr.Zero)
            Dim value As Single = DirectCast(meter, IAudioMeterInformation).GetPeakValue()
            Return Not (value <= 0.0F)
        Finally
            If mediaDevice IsNot Nothing Then Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mediaDevice)
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Shared Function GetVolume() As Integer
        Dim fVolume As Single
        Dim masterVol As IAudioEndpointVolume = GetMasterVolumeObject()
        Try
            masterVol.GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(fVolume)
            Return CType(fVolume * 100, Integer)
        Finally
            If masterVol IsNot Nothing Then Marshal.ReleaseComObject(masterVol)
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Shared Function SetVolume(volume As Integer) As Integer
        volume = Math.Max(Math.Min(volume, 100), 0)
        Dim masterVolume As IAudioEndpointVolume = GetMasterVolumeObject()
        Try
            Dim prevVolume = GetVolume()
            masterVolume.SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(volume / 100.0F, Guid.Empty)
            Return prevVolume
        Finally
            If masterVolume IsNot Nothing Then Marshal.ReleaseComObject(masterVolume)
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Shared Sub VolumeUp()
        Dim masterVol As IAudioEndpointVolume = GetMasterVolumeObject()
        Try
            masterVol.VolumeStepUp(Guid.Empty)
        Finally
            If masterVol IsNot Nothing Then Marshal.ReleaseComObject(masterVol)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub VolumeDown()
        Dim masterVol As IAudioEndpointVolume = GetMasterVolumeObject()
        Try
            masterVol.VolumeStepDown(Guid.Empty)
        Finally
            If masterVol IsNot Nothing Then Marshal.ReleaseComObject(masterVol)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Friend Shared Function GetMasterVolumeObject() As IAudioEndpointVolume
        Dim mediaDevice As IMMDevice = GetDefaultAudioEndpoint()
        Try
            Dim ppEndpoint = mediaDevice.Activate(GetType(IAudioEndpointVolume).GUID, CLSCTX.CLSCTX_ALL, IntPtr.Zero)
            Return DirectCast(ppEndpoint, IAudioEndpointVolume)
        Finally
            If mediaDevice IsNot Nothing Then Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mediaDevice)
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Shared Function GetDefaultAudioEndpoint() As IMMDevice
        Dim mediaDevice As IMMDevice = Nothing
        Dim deviceEnumerator = DirectCast(New MMDeviceEnumeratorComObject(), IMMDeviceEnumerator)
        Try
            deviceEnumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eMultimedia, mediaDevice)
            Return mediaDevice
        Finally
            If deviceEnumerator IsNot Nothing Then Marshal.ReleaseComObject(deviceEnumerator)
        End Try
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Very underappreciated answer. It's very annoying when checking for one thing in your project ie: if volume is muted or not, to have to carry around an annoying coreaudio.dll resource file along. It sticks out like a sore thumb when its the only "external" recourse needed to run your project. Nice work.

Answer (score 6):

Using C/C++ and having some knowledge with *directshow* is quite straight forward but with C# you need some kind of wrapper to make the calls. To be honest I don't use managed languages to use low level libraries but likely I found code for your case:

```
    private int IsMuted() {
        IAudioEndpointVolume masterVol = null;

        try {
            masterVol = GetMasterVolumeObject();
            if( masterVol == null )
                return -1; //error

            bool isMuted;
            masterVol.GetMute( out isMuted );

            return Convert.ToInt32( isMuted );
        }
        finally {
            if( masterVol != null )
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject( masterVol );
        }
    }

    private IAudioEndpointVolume GetMasterVolumeObject() {
        IMMDeviceEnumerator deviceEnumerator = null;
        IMMDevice speakers = null;
        try {
            deviceEnumerator = (IMMDeviceEnumerator)( new MMDeviceEnumerator() );
            deviceEnumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint( EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eMultimedia, out speakers );

            Guid IID_IAudioEndpointVolume = typeof( IAudioEndpointVolume ).GUID;
            object o;
            speakers.Activate( ref IID_IAudioEndpointVolume, 0, IntPtr.Zero, out o );
            IAudioEndpointVolume masterVol = (IAudioEndpointVolume)o;

            return masterVol;
        }
        finally {
            if( speakers != null ) Marshal.ReleaseComObject( speakers );
            if( deviceEnumerator != null ) Marshal.ReleaseComObject( deviceEnumerator );
        }
    }
```

COM interfaces from *Windows CoreAudio API*:

```
    [ComImport]
    [Guid( "BCDE0395-E52F-467C-8E3D-C4579291692E" )]
    internal class MMDeviceEnumerator {
    }

    internal enum EDataFlow {
        eRender,
        eCapture,
        eAll,
        EDataFlow_enum_count
    }

    internal enum ERole {
        eConsole,
        eMultimedia,
        eCommunications,
        ERole_enum_count
    }

    [Guid( "A95664D2-9614-4F35-A746-DE8DB63617E6" ), InterfaceType( ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown )]
    internal interface IMMDeviceEnumerator {
        int NotImpl1();

        [PreserveSig]
        int GetDefaultAudioEndpoint( EDataFlow dataFlow, ERole role, out IMMDevice ppDevice );

        // the rest is not implemented
    }

    [Guid( "D666063F-1587-4E43-81F1-B948E807363F" ), InterfaceType( ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown )]
    internal interface IMMDevice {
        [PreserveSig]
        int Activate( ref Guid iid, int dwClsCtx, IntPtr pActivationParams, [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.IUnknown )] out object ppInterface );

        // the rest is not implemented
    }

    // http://netcoreaudio.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#trunk/Code/CoreAudio/Interfaces/IAudioEndpointVolume.cs
    [Guid( "5CDF2C82-841E-4546-9722-0CF74078229A" ), InterfaceType( ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown )]
    public interface IAudioEndpointVolume {
        [PreserveSig]
        int NotImpl1();

        [PreserveSig]
        int NotImpl2();

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a count of the channels in the audio stream.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="channelCount">The number of channels.</param>
        /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetChannelCount(
            [Out] [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.U4 )] out UInt32 channelCount );

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the master volume level of the audio stream, in decibels.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="level">The new master volume level in decibels.</param>
        /// <param name="eventContext">A user context value that is passed to the notification callback.</param>
        /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
        [PreserveSig]
        int SetMasterVolumeLevel(
            [In] [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.R4 )] float level,
            [In] [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPStruct )] Guid eventContext );

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the master volume level, expressed as a normalized, audio-tapered value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="level">The new master volume level expressed as a normalized value between 0.0 and 1.0.</param>
        /// <param name="eventContext">A user context value that is passed to the notification callback.</param>
        /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
        [PreserveSig]
        int SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(
            [In] [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.R4 )] float level,
            [In] [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPStruct )] Guid eventContext );

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the master volume level of the audio stream, in decibels.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="level">The volume level in decibels.</param>
        /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetMasterVolumeLevel(
            [Out] [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.R4 )] out float level );

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the master volume level, expressed as a normalized, audio-tapered value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="level">The volume level expressed as a normalized value between 0.0 and 1.0.</param>
        /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(
            [Out] [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.R4 )] out float level );

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the volume level, in decibels, of the specified channel of the audio stream.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="channelNumber">The channel number.</param>
        /// <param name="level">The new volume level in decibels.</param>
        /// <param name="eventContext">A user context value that is passed to the notification callback.</param>
        /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
        [PreserveSig]
        int SetChannelVolumeLevel(
            [In] [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.U4 )] UInt32 channelNumber,
            [In] [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.R4 )] float level,
            [In] [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPStruct )] Guid eventContext );

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the normalized, audio-tapered volume level of the specified channel in the audio stream.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="channelNumber">The channel number.</param>
        /// <param name="level">The new master volume level expressed as a normalized value between 0.0 and 1.0.</param>
        /// <param name="eventContext">A user context value that is passed to the notification callback.</param>
        /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
        [PreserveSig]
        int SetChannelVolumeLevelScalar(
            [In] [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.U4 )] UInt32 channelNumber,
            [In] [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.R4 )] float level,
            [In] [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPStruct )] Guid eventContext );

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the volume level, in decibels, of the specified channel in the audio stream.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="channelNumber">The zero-based channel number.</param>
        /// <param name="level">The volume level in decibels.</param>
        /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetChannelVolumeLevel(
            [In] [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.U4 )] UInt32 channelNumber,
            [Out] [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.R4 )] out float level );

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the normalized, audio-tapered volume level of the specified channel of the audio stream.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="channelNumber">The zero-based channel number.</param>
        /// <param name="level">The volume level expressed as a normalized value between 0.0 and 1.0.</param>
        /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetChannelVolumeLevelScalar(
            [In] [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.U4 )] UInt32 channelNumber,
            [Out] [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.R4 )] out float level );

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the muting state of the audio stream.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="isMuted">True to mute the stream, or false to unmute the stream.</param>
        /// <param name="eventContext">A user context value that is passed to the notification callback.</param>
        /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
        [PreserveSig]
        int SetMute(
            [In] [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.Bool )] Boolean isMuted,
            [In] [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPStruct )] Guid eventContext );

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the muting state of the audio stream.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="isMuted">The muting state. True if the stream is muted, false otherwise.</param>
        /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetMute(
            [Out] [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.Bool )] out Boolean isMuted );

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets information about the current step in the volume range.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="step">The current zero-based step index.</param>
        /// <param name="stepCount">The total number of steps in the volume range.</param>
        /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetVolumeStepInfo(
            [Out] [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.U4 )] out UInt32 step,
            [Out] [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.U4 )] out UInt32 stepCount );

        /// <summary>
        /// Increases the volume level by one step.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="eventContext">A user context value that is passed to the notification callback.</param>
        /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
        [PreserveSig]
        int VolumeStepUp(
            [In] [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPStruct )] Guid eventContext );

        /// <summary>
        /// Decreases the volume level by one step.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="eventContext">A user context value that is passed to the notification callback.</param>
        /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
        [PreserveSig]
        int VolumeStepDown(
            [In] [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPStruct )] Guid eventContext );

        /// <summary>
        /// Queries the audio endpoint device for its hardware-supported functions.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hardwareSupportMask">A hardware support mask that indicates the capabilities of the endpoint.</param>
        /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
        [PreserveSig]
        int QueryHardwareSupport(
            [Out] [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.U4 )] out UInt32 hardwareSupportMask );

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the volume range of the audio stream, in decibels.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="volumeMin">The minimum volume level in decibels.</param>
        /// <param name="volumeMax">The maximum volume level in decibels.</param>
        /// <param name="volumeStep">The volume increment level in decibels.</param>
        /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetVolumeRange(
            [Out] [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.R4 )] out float volumeMin,
            [Out] [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.R4 )] out float volumeMax,
            [Out] [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.R4 )] out float volumeStep );
    }
```

[AudioManager.cs](https://gist.github.com/sverrirs/d099b34b7f72bb4fb386)

Comment: Yes something is wrong and I cant get anything to work with the things that  u guys have copy pasted from another site, found that before asking here, still dont understand what to do, but thanks anyway. private function getmute() as boolean
    Dim devenum As New MMDeviceEnumerator
    Dim device As MMDevice = devenum.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eMultimedia)
    If device.AudioEndpointVolume.Mute = True Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function What to change here to make it work without 600 lines of extra code

Comment: How do I use it to check if system is muted then? Nothing happens when adding it

Comment: @WTech. You call `IsMuted()`. If the return value is `1` then it is muted, if `0` not muted if `-1` something went wrong. Change `return isMuted;` to `return Convert.ToInt32( isMuted );`

Comment: I added the AudioManager.cs to my project and then         private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ismuted();
            
        } ,,,, result; Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0103 The name 'ismuted' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @WTech No need to add `AudioManager.cs`! Just copy paste my code which is part of it

Comment: private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((IsMuted() == -1))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hello Mute");
            }
        } Okey I did, but no messagebox appears when muted or not... :( Ony day of works just to check if system and muted and its still not working, computer going to die tonight

Comment: Now it works! I dont know how to thank u guys, but thank u very much! Now I'm so happy, thank thanks thanks!

Comment: @jimi Can you make an answer in vb.net, removing all the unnecessary code? Someone may stuck in translating the code from c#.

Comment: The *translation* is complete. I added some more methods (I needed to test it, so...). Give it a test drive. Btw, I didn't notice before, the Interface I thought was missing is indeed there, with another name:  `MMDeviceEnumerator` instead of `MMDeviceEnumeratorComObject`.