# C# [Out] [MarshalAs(..) to VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, migration

I'm converting a C# code to VB.NET, and the following line gives me a head ache:

```
    int GetChannelCount(
        [Out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out UInt32 channelCount);
```

The online converters don't know how to handle

```
[Out]
```

I understand "out" (that would be "ByRef"), but I don't know what "[Out]" does and how to convert that to VB.NET.

Thank you.

ps: This is the entire code if it's important:

http://netcoreaudio.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#trunk/Code/CoreAudio/Interfaces/IAudioEndpointVolume.cs

```
[Guid("5CDF2C82-841E-4546-9722-0CF74078229A"),InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IAudioEndpointVolume
{
    [PreserveSig]
    int NotImpl1();

    [PreserveSig]
    int NotImpl2();

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a count of the channels in the audio stream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="channelCount">The number of channels.</param>
    /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
    [PreserveSig]
    int GetChannelCount(
        [Out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out UInt32 channelCount);

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the master volume level of the audio stream, in decibels.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="level">The new master volume level in decibels.</param>
    /// <param name="eventContext">A user context value that is passed to the notification callback.</param>
    /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
    [PreserveSig]
    int SetMasterVolumeLevel(
        [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)] float level,
        [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid eventContext);

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the master volume level, expressed as a normalized, audio-tapered value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="level">The new master volume level expressed as a normalized value between 0.0 and 1.0.</param>
    /// <param name="eventContext">A user context value that is passed to the notification callback.</param>
    /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
    [PreserveSig]
    int SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(
        [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)] float level,
        [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid eventContext);

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the master volume level of the audio stream, in decibels.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="level">The volume level in decibels.</param>
    /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
    [PreserveSig]
    int GetMasterVolumeLevel(
        [Out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)] out float level);

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the master volume level, expressed as a normalized, audio-tapered value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="level">The volume level expressed as a normalized value between 0.0 and 1.0.</param>
    /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
    [PreserveSig]
    int GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(
        [Out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)] out float level);

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the volume level, in decibels, of the specified channel of the audio stream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="channelNumber">The channel number.</param>
    /// <param name="level">The new volume level in decibels.</param>
    /// <param name="eventContext">A user context value that is passed to the notification callback.</param>
    /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
    [PreserveSig]
    int SetChannelVolumeLevel(
        [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] UInt32 channelNumber,
        [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)] float level,
        [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid eventContext);

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the normalized, audio-tapered volume level of the specified channel in the audio stream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="channelNumber">The channel number.</param>
    /// <param name="level">The new master volume level expressed as a normalized value between 0.0 and 1.0.</param>
    /// <param name="eventContext">A user context value that is passed to the notification callback.</param>
    /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
    [PreserveSig]
    int SetChannelVolumeLevelScalar(
        [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] UInt32 channelNumber,
        [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)] float level,
        [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid eventContext);

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the volume level, in decibels, of the specified channel in the audio stream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="channelNumber">The zero-based channel number.</param>
    /// <param name="level">The volume level in decibels.</param>
    /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
    [PreserveSig]
    int GetChannelVolumeLevel(
        [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] UInt32 channelNumber,
        [Out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)] out float level);

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the normalized, audio-tapered volume level of the specified channel of the audio stream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="channelNumber">The zero-based channel number.</param>
    /// <param name="level">The volume level expressed as a normalized value between 0.0 and 1.0.</param>
    /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
    [PreserveSig]
    int GetChannelVolumeLevelScalar(
        [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] UInt32 channelNumber,
        [Out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)] out float level);

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the muting state of the audio stream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="isMuted">True to mute the stream, or false to unmute the stream.</param>
    /// <param name="eventContext">A user context value that is passed to the notification callback.</param>
    /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
    [PreserveSig]
    int SetMute(
        [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] Boolean isMuted,
        [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid eventContext);

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the muting state of the audio stream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="isMuted">The muting state. True if the stream is muted, false otherwise.</param>
    /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
    [PreserveSig]
    int GetMute(
        [Out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] out Boolean isMuted);

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets information about the current step in the volume range.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="step">The current zero-based step index.</param>
    /// <param name="stepCount">The total number of steps in the volume range.</param>
    /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
    [PreserveSig]
    int GetVolumeStepInfo(
        [Out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out UInt32 step,
        [Out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out UInt32 stepCount);

    /// <summary>
    /// Increases the volume level by one step.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="eventContext">A user context value that is passed to the notification callback.</param>
    /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
    [PreserveSig]
    int VolumeStepUp(
        [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid eventContext);

    /// <summary>
    /// Decreases the volume level by one step.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="eventContext">A user context value that is passed to the notification callback.</param>
    /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
    [PreserveSig]
    int VolumeStepDown(
        [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid eventContext);

    /// <summary>
    /// Queries the audio endpoint device for its hardware-supported functions.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hardwareSupportMask">A hardware support mask that indicates the capabilities of the endpoint.</param>
    /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
    [PreserveSig]
    int QueryHardwareSupport(
        [Out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out UInt32 hardwareSupportMask);

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the volume range of the audio stream, in decibels.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="volumeMin">The minimum volume level in decibels.</param>
    /// <param name="volumeMax">The maximum volume level in decibels.</param>
    /// <param name="volumeStep">The volume increment level in decibels.</param>
    /// <returns>An HRESULT code indicating whether the operation passed of failed.</returns>
    [PreserveSig]
    int GetVolumeRange(
        [Out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)] out float volumeMin,
        [Out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)] out float volumeMax,
        [Out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)] out float volumeStep);
}
```

Comment: We have already tackled this exact matter in a previous question. See here [How to check if the system audio is muted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52001368/how-to-check-if-the-system-audio-is-muted?answertab=active#tab-top).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`out` is a modifier that causes the parameter to be passed by ref without the need to be initialized first as is the case with `ref` in C#. It is meant to write a value to the parameter passed so the direction of modification is out of the called method. Consider the `TryParse()` methods in some of the .NET Framework types.

```
string foo = "123";
int value;
if(int.TryParse(foo, out value)) // Returns true if it can be parsed in which case, value now holds the parsed value
{
    // Do something
}
```

VB.NET does not have an equivalent for this because it initializes variables by default and you just call it `ByRef` as normal. In the context of using it with platform invoke as the code you posted is doing, you only need to call the `Out` attribute which has the same effect for platform invoke, by causing data to be marshalled from the called method to the calling method. Consider the following code:

```
<PreserveSig>
Function GetChannelCount(<Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)> ByRef channelCount As UInt32) As Integer

End Function
```

This essentially tells the runtime that the `ByRef` parameter you defined should be treated as an out parameter so to speak allowing the called method to write to it without needing it to be initialized first.

Comment: Thank you! Great explanation!

Comment: Not the downvoter, but you're mixing up the [Out Attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.outattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) and the [`out` parameter modifier (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier). The first part of your answer should be re-written to be more clear. The second part... to reconsider.

Comment: Ok, I gave the loose description as I thought it would suffice in this context. Let me clarify