# Enable/disable mic playback from vb.net?

Tags: windows, vb.net, audio, registry

I want to be able to enable/disable the windows mic playback from a .net app, command line or Dll call

I have tried to modify the registry, and it does work, but I have to restart the audio service for the changes to apply.
I tried to search for windows API calls to force the audio service to reload its settings too but didn't find anything

```
Private Sub setPlaybackState(enabled As Boolean)
        Dim p As New Process
        'Runs PlaybackEnable.reg or PlaybackDisable.reg to set registry entries
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "Playback" & If(enabled, "Enable", "Disable") & ".reg"
        p.Start()
    End Sub
```

Comment: If you're talking about this  : [enable/disable audio device](https://i.ibb.co/VS9DfWg/Enable-Disable-Audio-Device.jpg) (in french),
it is done with **Core Audio APIs** (I can post a code sample with P/Invoke if needed)

Comment: No, I'm talking about [this](https://i.ibb.co/S54j9S2/Untitled.png)

Comment: It is the same Device ID on my configuration.
On the first tab, I have :
[Microphone Properties](https://i.ibb.co/ZcJNGTC/Microphone-Properties.jpg)

Then when I disable it : (manually or by code with APIs)
[Microphone Properties disabled](https://i.ibb.co/tbmkSnS/Microphone-Properties-disabled.jpg)

Comment: Try the CoreAudio methods shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52013031/7444103). There's no Device selector (yet, I will implement it one of these days), but it may work anyway, muting the master audio output or setting the Volume.

Comment: I changed my audio drivers settings so now I have 2 microphones (I need 1 enabled always) and @Castorix solution is valid for me. The microphone I want to mute isn't the default one. Now, I still can't disable mic through regedit, does anyone know any API or .exe to make this?

Comment: I did this basic sample with Core Audio APIs (no icons, no notifications, ...) =>
 [Disable Audo device](https://i.ibb.co/hmTWK5k/Disable-Audio-Device2.gif)
 If it is sufficient, I can post it (I have only 1 Microphone but it should work with 2...)

Comment: @Castorix sure, that's exactly what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the discussion with Hackeitos,

a sample using *Core Audio APIs* (tested on Windows 10, VS 2015)

To be improved : adding icons (I just got the path), using *IMMNotificationClient* for notifications, ...

[image: https://i.ibb.co/dLHcHtt/VB-Core-Audio.jpg]

```
Option Strict On
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

    Public Enum HRESULT As Integer
        S_OK = 0
        S_FALSE = 1
        E_NOINTERFACE = &H80004002
        E_NOTIMPL = &H80004001
        E_FAIL = &H80004005
        E_UNEXPECTED = &H8000FFFF
    End Enum

    <ComImport, Guid("886D8EEB-8CF2-4446-8D02-CDBA1DBDCF99"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)>
    Interface IPropertyStore
        Function GetCount(<Out> ByRef propertyCount As UInteger) As HRESULT
        Function GetAt(<[In]> ByVal propertyIndex As UInteger, <Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)> ByRef key As PROPERTYKEY) As HRESULT
        Function GetValue(<[In], MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)> ByRef key As PROPERTYKEY, <Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)> ByRef pv As PROPVARIANT) As HRESULT
        Function SetValue(<[In], MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)> ByRef key As PROPERTYKEY, <[In], MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)> ByRef pv As PROPVARIANT) As HRESULT
        Function Commit() As HRESULT
    End Interface

    Public Const STGM_READ As Integer = &H0
    Public Const STGM_WRITE As Integer = &H1
    Public Const STGM_READWRITE As Integer = &H2

    Public Structure PROPERTYKEY
        Public Sub New(ByVal InputId As Guid, ByVal InputPid As UInt32)
            fmtid = InputId
            pid = InputPid
        End Sub

        Private fmtid As Guid
        Private pid As UInteger
    End Structure

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
    Public Structure PROPARRAY
        Public cElems As UInt32
        Public pElems As IntPtr
    End Structure

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack:=1)>
    Public Structure PROPVARIANT
        <FieldOffset(0)>
        Public varType As UShort
        <FieldOffset(2)>
        Public wReserved1 As UShort
        <FieldOffset(4)>
        Public wReserved2 As UShort
        <FieldOffset(6)>
        Public wReserved3 As UShort
        <FieldOffset(8)>
        Public bVal As Byte
        <FieldOffset(8)>
        Public cVal As SByte
        <FieldOffset(8)>
        Public uiVal As UShort
        <FieldOffset(8)>
        Public iVal As Short
        <FieldOffset(8)>
        Public uintVal As UInt32
        <FieldOffset(8)>
        Public intVal As Int32
        <FieldOffset(8)>
        Public ulVal As UInt64
        <FieldOffset(8)>
        Public lVal As Int64
        <FieldOffset(8)>
        Public fltVal As Single
        <FieldOffset(8)>
        Public dblVal As Double
        <FieldOffset(8)>
        Public boolVal As Short
        <FieldOffset(8)>
        Public pclsidVal As IntPtr
        <FieldOffset(8)>
        Public pszVal As IntPtr
        <FieldOffset(8)>
        Public pwszVal As IntPtr
        <FieldOffset(8)>
        Public punkVal As IntPtr
        <FieldOffset(8)>
        Public ca As PROPARRAY
        <FieldOffset(8)>
        Public filetime As System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME
    End Structure

    Public Enum EDataFlow
        eRender = 0
        eCapture = (eRender + 1)
        eAll = (eCapture + 1)
        EDataFlow_enum_count = (eAll + 1)
    End Enum

    Public Enum ERole
        eConsole = 0
        eMultimedia = (eConsole + 1)
        eCommunications = (eMultimedia + 1)
        ERole_enum_count = (eCommunications + 1)
    End Enum

    <ComImport>
    <Guid("A95664D2-9614-4F35-A746-DE8DB63617E6")>
    <InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)>
    Interface IMMDeviceEnumerator
        Function EnumAudioEndpoints(ByVal dataFlow As EDataFlow, ByVal dwStateMask As Integer, <Out> ByRef ppDevices As IMMDeviceCollection) As HRESULT
        ' for 0x80070490 : Element not found
        <PreserveSig>
        Function GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(ByVal dataFlow As EDataFlow, ByVal role As ERole, <Out> ByRef ppEndpoint As IMMDevice) As HRESULT
        Function GetDevice(ByVal pwstrId As String, <Out> ByRef ppDevice As IMMDevice) As HRESULT
        Function RegisterEndpointNotificationCallback(ByVal pClient As IMMNotificationClient) As HRESULT
        Function UnregisterEndpointNotificationCallback(ByVal pClient As IMMNotificationClient) As HRESULT
    End Interface

    Public Const DEVICE_STATE_ACTIVE As Integer = &H1
    Public Const DEVICE_STATE_DISABLED As Integer = &H2
    Public Const DEVICE_STATE_NOTPRESENT As Integer = &H4
    Public Const DEVICE_STATE_UNPLUGGED As Integer = &H8
    Public Const DEVICE_STATEMASK_ALL As Integer = &HF

    <ComImport>
    <Guid("0BD7A1BE-7A1A-44DB-8397-CC5392387B5E")>
    <InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)>
    Interface IMMDeviceCollection
        Function GetCount(<Out> ByRef pcDevices As UInteger) As HRESULT
        Function Item(ByVal nDevice As UInteger, <Out> ByRef ppDevice As IMMDevice) As HRESULT
    End Interface

    <ComImport>
    <Guid("D666063F-1587-4E43-81F1-B948E807363F")>
    <InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)>
    Interface IMMDevice
        Function Activate(ByRef iid As Guid, ByVal dwClsCtx As Integer, ByRef pActivationParams As PROPVARIANT, <Out> ByRef ppInterface As IntPtr) As HRESULT
        Function OpenPropertyStore(ByVal stgmAccess As Integer, <Out> ByRef ppProperties As IPropertyStore) As HRESULT
        Function GetId(<Out> ByRef ppstrId As IntPtr) As HRESULT
        Function GetState(<Out> ByRef pdwState As Integer) As HRESULT
    End Interface

    <ComImport>
    <Guid("7991EEC9-7E89-4D85-8390-6C703CEC60C0")>
    <InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)>
    Interface IMMNotificationClient
        Function OnDeviceStateChanged(ByVal pwstrDeviceId As String, ByVal dwNewState As Integer) As HRESULT
        Function OnDeviceAdded(ByVal pwstrDeviceId As String) As HRESULT
        Function OnDeviceRemoved(ByVal pwstrDeviceId As String) As HRESULT
        Function OnDefaultDeviceChanged(ByVal flow As EDataFlow, ByVal role As ERole, ByVal pwstrDefaultDeviceId As String) As HRESULT
        Function OnPropertyValueChanged(ByVal pwstrDeviceId As String, ByRef key As PROPERTYKEY) As HRESULT
    End Interface

    <ComImport>
    <Guid("1BE09788-6894-4089-8586-9A2A6C265AC5")>
    <InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)>
    Interface IMMEndpoint
        Function GetDataFlow(<Out> ByRef pDataFlow As EDataFlow) As HRESULT
    End Interface

    <ComImport>
    <Guid("f8679f50-850a-41cf-9c72-430f290290c8")>
    <InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)>
    Interface IPolicyConfig
        Function GetMixFormat(<[In]> <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByVal pszDeviceName As String, <Out> ByRef ppFormat As WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE) As HRESULT
        Function GetDeviceFormat(<[In]> <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByVal pszDeviceName As String, <[In]> <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> ByVal bDefault As Boolean, <Out> ByRef ppFormat As WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE) As HRESULT
        Function ResetDeviceFormat(<[In]> <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByVal pszDeviceName As String) As HRESULT
        Function SetDeviceFormat(<[In]> <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByVal pszDeviceName As String, <[In]> <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)> ByVal pEndpointFormat As WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE,
                                 <[In]> <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)> ByVal pMixFormat As WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE) As HRESULT
        Function GetProcessingPeriod(<[In]> <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByVal pszDeviceName As String, <[In]> <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> ByVal bDefault As Boolean, <Out> ByRef pmftDefaultPeriod As Int64, <Out> ByRef pmftMinimumPeriod As Int64) As HRESULT
        Function SetProcessingPeriod(<[In]> <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByVal pszDeviceName As String, ByVal pmftPeriod As Int64) As HRESULT
        Function GetShareMode(<[In]> <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByVal pszDeviceName As String, <Out> ByRef pMode As DeviceShareMode) As HRESULT
        Function SetShareMode(<[In]> <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByVal pszDeviceName As String, <[In]> ByVal mode As DeviceShareMode) As HRESULT
        Function GetPropertyValue(<[In]> <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByVal pszDeviceName As String, <[In]> <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> ByVal bFxStore As Boolean, ByRef pKey As PROPERTYKEY, <Out> ByRef pv As PROPVARIANT) As HRESULT
        Function SetPropertyValue(<[In]> <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByVal pszDeviceName As String, <[In]> <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> ByVal bFxStore As Boolean, <[In]> ByRef pKey As PROPERTYKEY, ByRef pv As PROPVARIANT) As HRESULT
        Function SetDefaultEndpoint(<[In]> <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByVal pszDeviceName As String, <[In]> <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)> ByVal role As ERole) As HRESULT
        Function SetEndpointVisibility(<[In]> <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByVal pszDeviceName As String, <[In]> <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> ByVal bVisible As Boolean) As HRESULT
    End Interface

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack:=1)>
    Public Class WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE
        Inherits WAVEFORMATEX

        <FieldOffset(0)>
        Public wValidBitsPerSample As Short
        <FieldOffset(0)>
        Public wSamplesPerBlock As Short
        <FieldOffset(0)>
        Public wReserved As Short
        <FieldOffset(2)>
        Public dwChannelMask As WaveMask
        <FieldOffset(6)>
        Public SubFormat As Guid
    End Class

    <Flags>
    Public Enum WaveMask
        None = &H0
        FrontLeft = &H1
        FrontRight = &H2
        FrontCenter = &H4
        LowFrequency = &H8
        BackLeft = &H10
        BackRight = &H20
        FrontLeftOfCenter = &H40
        FrontRightOfCenter = &H80
        BackCenter = &H100
        SideLeft = &H200
        SideRight = &H400
        TopCenter = &H800
        TopFrontLeft = &H1000
        TopFrontCenter = &H2000
        TopFrontRight = &H4000
        TopBackLeft = &H8000
        TopBackCenter = &H10000
        TopBackRight = &H20000
    End Enum

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack:=2)>
    Public Class WAVEFORMATEX
        Public wFormatTag As Short
        Public nChannels As Short
        Public nSamplesPerSec As Integer
        Public nAvgBytesPerSec As Integer
        Public nBlockAlign As Short
        Public wBitsPerSample As Short
        Public cbSize As Short
    End Class

    Public Enum DeviceShareMode
        [Shared]
        Exclusive
    End Enum

    <DllImport("Shlwapi.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
    Public Shared Function PathParseIconLocationW(pszIconFile As String) As Integer
    End Function

    Public Shared PKEY_Device_FriendlyName As PROPERTYKEY = New PROPERTYKEY(New Guid("a45c254e-df1c-4efd-8020-67d146a850e0"), 14)
    Public Shared PKEY_Device_DeviceDesc As PROPERTYKEY = New PROPERTYKEY(New Guid("a45c254e-df1c-4efd-8020-67d146a850e0"), 2)
    Public Shared PKEY_DeviceClass_IconPath As PROPERTYKEY = New PROPERTYKEY(New Guid("259abffc-50a7-47ce-af08-68c9a7d73366"), 12)

    Friend WithEvents ListView1 As ListView
    Friend WithEvents Button1 As Button
    Friend WithEvents Button2 As Button
    Dim groupRender As New ListViewGroup("Render")
    Dim groupCapture As New ListViewGroup("Capture")
    Dim colorDefault As Color = Color.GreenYellow

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(800, 304)
        Me.Text = "Test Core Audio APIs"

        ListView1 = New ListView()
        ListView1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(10, 10)
        ListView1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(780, 230)
        ListView1.Columns.Add("Device Name", 320, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        ListView1.Columns.Add("Device ID", 350, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        ListView1.Columns.Add("State", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        ListView1.View = View.Details
        ListView1.FullRowSelect = True
        ListView1.HideSelection = False
        ListView1.MultiSelect = False
        Controls.Add(ListView1)

        ListView1.Groups.Add(groupRender)
        ListView1.Groups.Add(groupCapture)

        Button1 = New Button()
        Button1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(10, 260)
        Button1.Name = "Button1"
        Button1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
        Button1.TabIndex = 0
        Button1.Text = "Enable"
        Button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        Controls.Add(Button1)
        Button1.Enabled = False

        Button2 = New Button()
        Button2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(95, 260)
        Button2.Name = "Button2"
        Button2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(100, 23)
        Button2.TabIndex = 1
        Button2.Text = "Set as Default"
        Button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        Controls.Add(Button2)
        Button2.Enabled = False

        CenterToScreen()
        PopulateListView()
    End Sub

    Private Sub PopulateListView()
        Dim hr As HRESULT = HRESULT.E_FAIL
        Dim CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator As Guid = New Guid("{BCDE0395-E52F-467C-8E3D-C4579291692E}")
        Dim MMDeviceEnumeratorType As Type = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator, True)
        Dim MMDeviceEnumerator As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(MMDeviceEnumeratorType)
        Dim pMMDeviceEnumerator As IMMDeviceEnumerator = CType(MMDeviceEnumerator, IMMDeviceEnumerator)
        If (pMMDeviceEnumerator IsNot Nothing) Then
            Dim sIdDefaultRender As String = Nothing
            Dim sIdDefaultCapture As String = Nothing
            Dim pDefaultDevice As IMMDevice = Nothing
            hr = pMMDeviceEnumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eConsole, pDefaultDevice)
            If hr = HRESULT.S_OK Then
                Dim hGlobal As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(260)
                hr = pDefaultDevice.GetId(hGlobal)
                sIdDefaultRender = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(hGlobal)
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(hGlobal)
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pDefaultDevice)
            End If
            hr = pMMDeviceEnumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eCapture, ERole.eConsole, pDefaultDevice)
            If hr = HRESULT.S_OK Then
                Dim hGlobal As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(260)
                hr = pDefaultDevice.GetId(hGlobal)
                sIdDefaultCapture = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(hGlobal)
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(hGlobal)
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pDefaultDevice)
            End If

            Dim pDeviceCollection As IMMDeviceCollection = Nothing
            hr = pMMDeviceEnumerator.EnumAudioEndpoints(EDataFlow.eAll, DEVICE_STATE_ACTIVE Or DEVICE_STATE_UNPLUGGED Or DEVICE_STATE_DISABLED, pDeviceCollection)
            If (hr = HRESULT.S_OK) Then
                Dim nDevices As UInteger = 0
                hr = pDeviceCollection.GetCount(nDevices)
                For i As UInteger = 0 To CUInt(nDevices - 1)
                    Dim pDevice As IMMDevice = Nothing
                    hr = pDeviceCollection.Item(i, pDevice)
                    If (hr = HRESULT.S_OK) Then
                        Dim pPropertyStore As IPropertyStore = Nothing
                        hr = pDevice.OpenPropertyStore(STGM_READ, pPropertyStore)
                        If hr = HRESULT.S_OK Then

                            Dim sFriendlyName As String = Nothing
                            Dim pv As PROPVARIANT = New PROPVARIANT()
                            hr = pPropertyStore.GetValue(PKEY_Device_FriendlyName, pv)
                            If hr = HRESULT.S_OK Then
                                sFriendlyName = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(pv.pwszVal)
                            End If

                            Dim sIconPath As String = Nothing
                            Dim nIconId As Integer = 0
                            Dim pvIconPath As PROPVARIANT = New PROPVARIANT()
                            hr = pPropertyStore.GetValue(PKEY_DeviceClass_IconPath, pvIconPath)
                            If hr = HRESULT.S_OK Then
                                ' %windir%\system32\mmres.dll,-3011
                                sIconPath = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(pvIconPath.pwszVal)
                                nIconId = PathParseIconLocationW(sIconPath)
                            End If

                            Dim hGlobal As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(260)
                            hr = pDevice.GetId(hGlobal)
                            Dim sId As String = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(hGlobal)
                            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(hGlobal)

                            Dim pEndpoint As IMMEndpoint = Nothing
                            pEndpoint = CType(pDevice, IMMEndpoint)
                            Dim eDirection As EDataFlow = EDataFlow.eAll
                            hr = pEndpoint.GetDataFlow(eDirection)

                            Dim nState As Integer = 0
                            Dim sState As String = ""
                            hr = pDevice.GetState(nState)
                            If (nState = DEVICE_STATE_ACTIVE) Then
                                sState = "Active"
                            ElseIf (nState = DEVICE_STATE_DISABLED) Then
                                sState = "Disabled"
                            ElseIf (nState = DEVICE_STATE_NOTPRESENT) Then
                                sState = "Not present"
                            ElseIf (nState = DEVICE_STATE_UNPLUGGED) Then
                                sState = "Unplugged"
                            End If

                            Dim lvi As ListViewItem = Nothing
                            If (eDirection = EDataFlow.eRender) Then
                                lvi = ListView1.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String() {sFriendlyName, sId, sState}, groupRender))
                            ElseIf (eDirection = EDataFlow.eCapture) Then
                                lvi = ListView1.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String() {sFriendlyName, sId, sState}, groupCapture))
                            End If
                            If (sId = sIdDefaultRender) Then
                                lvi.BackColor = colorDefault
                            End If
                            If (sId = sIdDefaultCapture) Then
                                lvi.BackColor = colorDefault
                            End If
                            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pPropertyStore)
                        End If
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pDevice)
                    End If
                Next
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pDeviceCollection)
            End If
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pMMDeviceEnumerator)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListView1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim selitems As ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection = ListView1.SelectedItems
        Dim item As ListViewItem
        Dim nDevInst As Integer = 0
        Dim bEnabled As Boolean = False
        Dim sState As String = Nothing
        For Each item In selitems
            sState = item.SubItems(2).Text
            If (sState = "Disabled") Then
                Button1.Text = "Enable"
            Else
                Button1.Text = "Disable"
            End If
            If (item.BackColor <> colorDefault And sState = "Active") Then
                Button2.Enabled = True
            Else
                Button2.Enabled = False
            End If
        Next
        Button1.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim hr As HRESULT = HRESULT.E_FAIL
        Dim CLSID_PolicyConfig As Guid = New Guid("{870af99c-171d-4f9e-af0d-e63df40c2bc9}")
        Dim PolicyConfigType As Type = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(CLSID_PolicyConfig, True)
        Dim PolicyConfig As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(PolicyConfigType)
        Dim pPolicyConfig As IPolicyConfig = CType(PolicyConfig, IPolicyConfig)

        Dim sCurrentId As String = ListView1.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems(1).Text
        Dim sState As String = ListView1.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems(2).Text
        Dim bEnable As Boolean = False
        If pPolicyConfig IsNot Nothing Then
            If (sState = "Disabled") Then
                bEnable = True
            Else
                bEnable = False
            End If
            hr = pPolicyConfig.SetEndpointVisibility(sCurrentId, bEnable)
            Button1.Enabled = False
            Button2.Enabled = False
            ListView1.Items.Clear()
            PopulateListView()
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(PolicyConfig)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim hr As HRESULT = HRESULT.E_FAIL
        Dim CLSID_PolicyConfig As Guid = New Guid("{870af99c-171d-4f9e-af0d-e63df40c2bc9}")
        Dim PolicyConfigType As Type = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(CLSID_PolicyConfig, True)
        Dim PolicyConfig As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(PolicyConfigType)
        Dim pPolicyConfig As IPolicyConfig = CType(PolicyConfig, IPolicyConfig)

        Dim sCurrentId As String = ListView1.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems(1).Text
        Dim sState As String = ListView1.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems(2).Text
        Dim bEnable As Boolean = False
        If pPolicyConfig IsNot Nothing Then
            hr = pPolicyConfig.SetDefaultEndpoint(sCurrentId, ERole.eConsole)
            Button1.Enabled = False
            Button2.Enabled = False
            ListView1.Items.Clear()
            PopulateListView()
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(PolicyConfig)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```