# volume control in c#. How do I assign a value to the volume?

Tags: c#, volume

In my program I am able to increase the volume and decrease the volume using system variables such as

```
    private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE = 0x80000;
    private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP = 0xA0000;
    private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN = 0x90000;
    private const int WM_APPCOMMAND = 0x319;
```

but  is there a system variable that allows me to assign it a value.   Like for example to set the volume at 57 instead of increasing or decreasing to reach that value.

what would like to eventually do is to use a trackbar to adjust the volume.  trackbar should equal the system volume when dragging it in either direction for to change the volume accordingly.

Comment: might be [helpful](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7b721b58-d323-4f04-914a-d47389ad438d/how-to-volume-control?forum=vbgeneral)

Comment: You have [mixerSetControlDetails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmeapi/nf-mmeapi-mixersetcontroldetails) and CoreAudio's [IAudioEndpointVolume](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/endpointvolume/nn-endpointvolume-iaudioendpointvolume) interface [SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/endpointvolume/nf-endpointvolume-iaudioendpointvolume-setmastervolumelevelscalar) method. An implementation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52001368/7444103). The CoreAudio method, I've only implemented it in VB.Net.

Comment: If you don't *speak the language*, I can translate it to C#. It's almost the same thing, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NuGet package AudioSwitcher.AudioApi.CoreAudio as answered here:
[How to programmatically set the system volume?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139181/how-to-programmatically-set-the-system-volume)

Via code:

```
CoreAudioDevice defaultPlaybackDevice = new CoreAudioController().DefaultPlaybackDevice;
Debug.WriteLine("Current Volume:" + defaultPlaybackDevice.Volume);
defaultPlaybackDevice.Volume = 80;
```

Note: It sets volume in range [0;100] on default playback device if device muted it doesn't unmute it, so you should call if you want unmute it:

```
defaultPlaybackDevice.Mute(false);
```

For your purpose it also provide events VolumeChanged and MuteChanged to track internal volume changes.

Internally it used Core Audio APIs that is low level COM-based audio control API provided started Windows Vista.

If you want write own wrapper for doing such thing you should see IAudioEndpointVolume interface (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/endpointvolume/nn-endpointvolume-iaudioendpointvolume)

Internal volume notification implemented as callback within provided information in structure AUDIO_VOLUME_NOTIFICATION_DATA (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/endpointvolume/ns-endpointvolume-audio_volume_notification_data)

Also if you want that your app support Windows XP you should use legacy WinMM API and its function waveOutSetVolume.

Comment: thank you,  where can i get the audioswitcher api at.  when I try to use the code to does not recognize as coreaudiodevice as a valid data type.

Comment: Use NuGet Package Manager to install NuGet package in your project. Link to these nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/AudioSwitcher.AudioApi.CoreAudio/

Comment: thank you.  i was able to get the dll for github.  from someone else project.