# Check if system sounds are ON or OFF

Tags: windows, vb.net, system-sounds

I've a vb.net application which has a button; when I click the button it should display a message stating whether the system sounds are on or off.

How do I do it?

By System sounds I mean the sounds played by the system such as "Asterisk",  "hand" etc. These sounds usually occur when a message box pops up. These sounds can be turned off or on in the volume mixer. I want my application to on the click of a button show a message "System sounds are ON" or "... OFF" as a result of system sounds beings turned on or off in the volume mixer.

Below image shows system sounds turned off in the volume mixer window.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52001368/how-to-check-if-the-system-audio-is-muted

Comment: @J.ScottElblein I think it answers how to control the computer's audio and its not about controlling system sounds.

Comment: You can read from the registry to see if the current sound scheme is set to none. `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes` under the `(Default)` key.

Comment: @J.ScottElblein The value of (Default) is ".Default" and this value doesn't change if mute or unmute the system sounds

Comment: Mute is different from Off. Mute is the computer audio, like the above link.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19678359/how-to-check-the-master-volume-is-muted-or-not

Comment: @J.ScottElblein You are right. I actually meant on and off not unmute and mute.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the NuGet package `AudioSwitcher.AudioApi.CoreAudio` and the following code.

```
Imports AudioSwitcher.AudioApi.CoreAudio

Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim dev As CoreAudioDevice = New CoreAudioController().DefaultPlaybackDevice

        If dev.IsMuted Then
            Console.WriteLine("Volume muted.")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Volume not muted.")
        End If

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: I want to check if System Sounds are off and not the computer volume. I've edited the question for clarity.

Comment: Well that was NOT the original question!

Answer (score 1):

If you change the System sound scheme to "No Sounds" (meaning System sounds are all Off):

[image]

then the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes` default key will show as `.None`; else, it'll show the name of the scheme. You can test is system sounds are all off bu checking for `.None`.

```
    If Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes", "", String.Empty).ToString = ".None" Then

        Debug.Print("System Sounds are Off")

    Else

        Debug.Print("System Sounds are On")

    End If
```

Comment: But I'm OFFing and ONing the system sounds from the volume mixer. Doing so doesn't change the registry value you've mentioned.